# Mobile auto play live streaming

Tags: javascript, ios, html, mobile, streaming

We are developing an application that needs to auto play a live streaming video in mobile. At the moment we been only able to start the streaming by clicking over the video.

1. How to auto play live streaming video on mobile (inside the html)?
2. How to prevent the click over the video opening the mobile video player?

I've seen some articles saying neither are possible but both works on this site: [webcams.com](http://webcams.com) (adult)

Thanks,

Answer (score 1):

```
 <video autoplay = "autoplay" or "" (empty string) >
   <source src="movie.mp4" type="video/mp4">
   <source src="movie.ogg" type="video/ogg">
   Your browser does not support the video tag.
 </video>
```

autoplay Instructs the UA to automatically begin playback of the audio stream as soon as it can do so without stopping.
The `<video>` tag is supported in Internet Explorer 9+, Firefox, Opera, Chrome, and Safari.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same requirement before.
As I know, it is disable to auto play in some mobile browsers.
If your case can accept no auido, and then you can refer this [page](http://phoboslab.org/log/2013/09/html5-live-video-streaming-via-websockets).
It uses canvas and WebSocket to draw the video.